# Any DOM parsers that do not modify the DOM?

Tags: c#, php, .net, dom, html-parsing

I need to write a page, can use PHP or .NET, that will display the unmodified html for an element of another page.

The other page may not have valid HTML, but we want it to be returned unmodified.  We will not be selecting based on the invalid elements, but will select their parent element and need them returned unmodified.

An example HTML page that my page will be fetching:

```
<body>
<div>
<p>test1</p>
<br>
<p>test2
<p>test3</p>
</div>
</body>
```

So far everything I have tried attempts to fix the HTML, it makes the br in the example self closing and the second paragraph tags gets closed.

Is there anything out there that can do this?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want to return it unmodified, why are you bothering with a parser at all?

Comment: Perhaps you could tell us what you're trying to accomplish?  If the markup is invalid, then there are only two options for a parser: attempt to fix it or halt with an error.  If you don't want the parser to fix it, then why do you need a parser in the first place?  Why not just fetch the source as text using CURL or the like?

Comment: Yeah, like Peter Geer said: you probably want something impossible. A parser depends on valid markup, and getting the parent of a faulty DOM element is such a specific thing... you probably wont find that.

Comment: PHP's DOM is **VERY** picky about invalid html, and will probably barf on even very slight malformations.

Comment: We're building an intranet site for training purposes that is to display HTML from other sites, unmodified.  I want the DOM parsing abilities so we can tell it which element we want (with everything within), but obviously the problems get introduced when it loads the items under that into its object.